# Parity Ethereum Public Node Operation not working

Tags: parity

Can't get `parity --public-node` to operate properly over LAN.

I am able to connect to the UI from another browser except it endlessly asks for a new signer token and does not let me get past.

Is this an issue that has been resolved?  Or is there something I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `--public-node` any more. From the [Parity documentation](https://wiki.parity.io/Public-Node):

> The flag `--public-node` has been deprecated and should not be used anymore. Parity Ethereum client does not support it anymore starting from v1.9.